# Concatenate rows based on name with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to concatenate rows of data from this source

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dherman/wc-demo/master/data/shakespeare-plays.csv

There are lines from the same speaker but they're broken into different rows in the dataframe. I'm trying to concatenate those speaker blocks into one row instead of 2+ rows.

Here's what I've tried but it doesn't work. I'm still learning pandas and python.

```
url = (r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dherman/wc-demo/master/data/shakespeare-plays.csv')
data = pd.read_csv(url, on_bad_lines='skip')
data.drop('I', inplace=True, axis=1)
data.drop('I.1', inplace=True, axis=1)
data.rename(columns={'In delivering my son from me, I bury a second husband.': 'Text', 'COUNTESS': 'Speaker'}, inplace=True)
data = data.groupby(['Speaker'])['Text'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't work?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It does concatenate, but it concatenates every line of that speaker into one long string. However, I want to keep each speech block in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little ugly, but you can group by consecutive values using a helper series based on `shift()` and `cumsum()`. Then aggregating in the group by:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dherman/wc-demo/master/data/shakespeare-plays.csv',on_bad_lines='skip', names=['act','scene','char','line'])
g = df['char'].ne(df['char'].shift()).cumsum().rename('speakernumber')
df = df.groupby(g).agg({'act':'first', 'scene':'first', 'char':'first', 'line': ' '.join}).reset_index()
```

I believe this will work across acts and scenes as well althought I didn't dig in deep enough to test.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I couldn't figure out the groupby without a good index, but this worked. Thanks!

Comment: I think the trick was to build that index on which to aggregate (`g` in this case). It's a similar approach in SQL where you would create a helper column using something like `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY char) as speakernumber` and then `GROUP BY act, scene, speakernumber` and aggregate using `string_agg()`/`list_agg()`. (If thinking through this in SQL is helpful).